# Pass hidden fields in Kendo Post for InLine Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, backend, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to pass Hidden Fields in Kendo Grid ?

```
columns.Bound(p => p.UserID).Hidden();
```

Above code didn't work.

Is there any other possible way ?

Comment: Can you post your full grid configuration as well as your controller methods for the grid? It's difficult if not impossible to tell what might be happening from the one line of code.

Comment: @G_P there should be fields that should be passed to the object to be recuperated in the DTO

Comment: please see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67419369/961631