# Pass hidden fields in Telerik grid row

Tags: asp.net-core, data-binding, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I use [Telerik grid](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid) in my asp.net core application.

I have a list of `Orders`, I need to bind some fields (like `CreatedBy`, by eg.) to be hidded, in order to get them when the user updates them.

I saw [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65507147/961631) without an answer.

my Code

```
@(Html.Kendo()
.Grid(Model)
.Name("Orders")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Width(190);
    columns.Bound(c => c.CreatedById).Hidden();
    columns.Bound(c => c.ModifiedById).Hidden();
    columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy(); }).Width(100);
})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Batch(true)
    .PageSize(20)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model => {
        model.Id(s => s.Id);
    })
    .Create(update => update.Action("BatchCreate", "Orders"))
    .Read(read => read.Action("BatchRead", "Orders"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("BatchUpdate", "Orders"))
    .Destroy(update => update.Action("BatchDestroy", "Orders"))
)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, solved it by adding the hidden fields to the datasource model:

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Width(190); // visible
    columns.Bound(c => c.HiddenId).Hidden();
    columns.Bound(c => c.HiddenOtherFiled).Hidden();
})
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(s => s.Id);
        model.Field(s => s.HiddenId);
        model.Field(s => s.HiddenOtherFiled);
    })
```